# Null Pointer When Access Data Structure Located Within Android Service

Tags: android, binding, service, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I have a service running in my Android application which contains a HashMap that I would like to use in an Activity.  So I bound the service to my activity and created a link between to two in order to use the data structure.

This is how I did it so far:

Activity (relevant code):

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        imService = ((IMService.IMBinder) service).getService();            
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        imService = null;
        Toast.makeText(ViewFlipperTest.this,
                R.string.local_service_stopped, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bindService(new Intent(ViewFlipperTest.this, IMService.class),
            mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE); 
                 .
                 .
                 .
}
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bindService(new Intent(ViewFlipperTest.this, IMService.class),
            mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);     
}

private void getMap(ViewFlipper flipper2) {

    Map<Integer, internalChatObj> tempMap = imService.getMapwData();
   }
```

Service (relevant code):

```
public class IMService extends Service implements IAppManager{
                .
                .
                .

public Map getMapwData(){
    if(getNumberOpenChats()>0){
        return openChatMapwData;
    }
    else
        return null;

}
}
```

Each time I try and run the method getMap(), I get a null pointer.  I even put a check to see if the imService was null and it was null each time.  It seems that it is trying to obtain the data from the Service but the binding to the service is null, is that right?  I have a check in the Service to send null if the map is empty, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Any help?

**Edit based on Will's tips**
New code

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        imService = ((IMService.IMBinder) service).getService();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        imService = null;
        Toast.makeText(ViewFlipperTest.this,
                R.string.local_service_stopped, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), null,"Loading..", true, false);
}
```

**Edit II**

IMBinder Class (Seems standard, no?)

```
public class IMBinder extends Binder {
    public IAppManager getService() {
        return IMService.this;
    }
}
```

Is it necessary to have IMService.this instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really seems like a timing issue; you shouldn't call the getMap function unless you are certain the imService variable exists, which is after a call to onServiceConnected.

Comment: getMap() is called after onCreate()  finishes, via a button press from another activity.  Is there an explicit way to call onServiceConnected? I can verify the onServiceConnected is called with a simple println which I've done already.  Even after verifying that, calling getMap() still results in a null pointer :-/

Comment: There is no assurance that the service is started when onCreate finishes (I guess you mean the call to getMap is the last instruction within onCreate?). Also onServiceConnected should not be called manually, instead Android will do this when it has finished binding the service. So you will have to disable all functionality that uses getMap until onServiceConnected has been called.

For example by putting your application within a 'loading' status or throwing a popup from the getMap when imService is null.

Comment: Is there a specific location in the code that is guaranteed that onServiceConnected is called and has returned? The last line of onCreate? In another function?

Comment: No there is not as it is unpredictable when Android finishes binding the service. That's exactly why it implements the onServiceConnected callback. A common pattern would be to set the loading screen in onCreate and bind the service, then init your app and hide the loading screen as soon as the onServiceConnected has been called. You are then safe to call getMap as long as you keep the service bound.

Comment: The updated code is blocking until the onServiceCreated method is called, but the same null pointer exception occurs.  I think it may be something else.

Comment: I assume you bind the service within the onCreate?

Comment: Yea, sorry, I forgot to put it in the updated code.  The binding occurs in the oncreate method immediately after the dialog box is shown.  The process happens so fast that the dialog box doesn't show.

Comment: If imService is still null, then you should check your IMService and specifically your IMBinder class to see if it returns the service as expected (which it apparently doesnt..).

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why it won't return IMService properly. I am using the service in another Activity and it works great, but here, when accessing the HashMap, IMService seems to be null.

Comment: I guess your imports are right, as it should give you an error if they aren't. You sure the name of the class doesn't interfere with other same-named classes? You could try using the full package name when referring to your IM classes.

Comment: Imports are correct.  Using the full name didn't change anything.  Very strange.

Comment: Did some more re-arranging, and turned out to be a timing problem as mentioned.  Thanks Will.

Comment: Cool you got it sorted out :)